# Geoserver WFS url parsing error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: ajax, geojson, geoserver

I am trying to get the json object from Geoserver 2.3.0 parsing the url and trying to overlay on map of openlayers.But unable to get the object. The error I am reciveing is: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Kal

I have tried getting with $.getJSON as well as $.ajax but error is the same.

I am using Geoserver 2.3.0 and Openlayers 2.13

code to get JSON object I am using:

```
   $('#getData').click(function(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/oifam/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=oifam:Kalamboli_WaterShed&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json';
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:url,
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
        }, 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    })
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the dataType: "jsonp" param from the request?

In the URL you're requesting a JSON and not a JSONP, for requesting JSONP regarding the GeoServer doc you have to build an URL like that:

```
var url = "http://"+ip+":"+port+"/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName="+remoteLayerName+"&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson";
```